# Making a div height 100%

Tags: html, height, css

I know there are quite a few questions on this already and i've looked around and everyone seems to say make the div absolutely positioned which is not really what i want to do.

Here's a jsbin minimal mockup which demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.

http://jsbin.com/uqosa6/

What i want is so that the grey div stretches along side the yellow div.

Does anyone know how one would go about this?

Comment: Google around for "css equal height columns". Plenty of methods out there. I've used this one (for 3 columns) a fair bit: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: @ Marc, i have not seen a better explanation (of the answer) to the "equal height columns" question. Supreme read.

Comment: @Marc make it an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google around for "css equal height columns". Plenty of methods out there. I've used this one (for 3 columns) a fair bit: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks